# req.url.indexOf('?') throws undefined error when trying to route to a controller with Express.router and passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?'); throws an error saying the statement to my left is undefined. Im using passportjs to create a login/registration page on my angular frontend. trying to make a post request to nodejs results in the above error. Im entirely new to the mean stack and ive tried several different tutorials to get myself up and running but have had some road blocks. can someone point in the right direction?
I've played around with just about every file moving around code and trying different solutions but nothing works, or one problem is solved but another occurs.

server.js

```
// set up ========================
var DATABASE = "mongodb://localhost:27017/smartHomeDevices";
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); //require monogDB Driver
var morgan = require("morgan"); // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require("method-override"); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var passport = require("passport");
//var _ = require("lodash");
var http = require('http');
//setup
//app.models =
require("./Models/moduleIndex");
//  Bring in the Passport config after model is defined
require('./config/passport');
//registering routes
var routes = require("./routes");
//Create App
var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());
//Add Middleware for REST API
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
}));
app.use(methodOverride("X-HTTP-Method-Override"));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
//CORS Support, makes API Public

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
    next();
});
app.use("/", routes);
// Connect to the db
mongoose.connect(DATABASE);
mongoose.connection.once("open", function() {
    var serv = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end();
        console.log(routes(req.method, req.url));
    }).listen(3000);
    //module.exports = app;
    console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

routes.js

```
//setup
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({
  secret: 'MY_SECRET',
  userProperty: 'payload'
});


var ctrlProfile = require('./Controllers/ProfileController');
var ctrlAuth = require('./Controllers/RegisterUserController');
// profile
router.get('/profile', auth, ctrlProfile.profileRead);

// authentication
router.post('/register', ctrlAuth.register);
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);

module.exports = router;
/*module.exports = {
  "/smartDevices" : require("./Controllers/SmartDeviceController"),
  "/registeredUsers": require("./Controllers/RegisterUserController")
};*/
```

resgisteredUsersControllers.js

```
//setup
//var Resource = require("resourcejs");
var restful = require("node-restful");
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('registeredUserModel');

var sendJSONresponse = function(res, status, content) {
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
};

module.exports.register = function(req,res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log("nw logging res");
  console.log(res);
    var user = new User();

    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.setPassword(req.body.password);

    user.save(function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      var token;
      token = user.generateJwt();
      res.status(200);
      res.json({
        "token" : token
      });
    });
    next();
};
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        var token;

        // If Passport throws/catches an error
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).json(err);
            return;
        }

        // If a user is found
        if (user) {
            token = user.generateJwt();
            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                "token": token
            });
        } else {
            // If user is not found
            res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res);
    next();
};
/*module.exports = function(app, route) {
    //setup controller for restful
    //  Resource(app,"",route,app.models.registeredUserModel).rest();
    var rest = restful.model("registeredUserModel",
        app.models.registeredUserModel
    ).methods(["get", "put", "post", "delete"]);
    rest.register(app, route);
    //return Middleware
    return function(req, res, next) {
        next();
    };
};
*/
```

ProfileController.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('registeredUserModel');

module.exports.profileRead = function(req, res) {

  // If no user ID exists in the JWT return a 401
  if (!req.payload._id) {
    res.status(401).json({
      "message" : "UnauthorizedError: private profile"
    });
  } else {
    // Otherwise continue
    User
      .findById(req.payload._id)
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        res.status(200).json(user);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't seem to contain anything like what is throwing the error?

Comment: @adeneo copied from terminal /home/trejon/RebelServer/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:140
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.handle (/home/trejon/RebelServer/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:140:27)
    at router (/home/trejon/RebelServer/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/trejon/RebelServer/src/server/server.js:97:21)

Comment: looks like know issue https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2399

Answer (score -1):

[Request](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req) object does not have `url` field.

Comment: Are you sure `request` object does not have `url` field? Becuase they have written **req.url is not a native Express property, it is inherited from Node’s http module.**